# Delete rows from multiple tables with foreign key constrain

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have a a database with tables worker_info, worker_skills, worker_url, worker_joining_date, worker_leaving_date, etc. The worker_info had a column called id which is foreign key to other tables.There are two cases I want to do when we delete a value from parent table:

Case 1: I want an optimised query to delete the values from the child tables(worker_skills, worker_url) when the info from worker_info is deleted.
I have tried stored procedure with variable but I am getting syntax error.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE worker_delete()
AS 
language plpgsql $$
DECLARE Del_Id int;
BEGIN
DECLARE Del_Id integer = (SELECT id 
FROM worker_info
WHERE Email = 'abc@gmail.com')
END;
$$;
```

I am getting following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "language"
LINE 3: language plpgsql $$
        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 35
```

Also after creating the procedure how can we include it in the delete statement? The below is not correct:

```
DELETE FROM worker_skills WHERE worker_id = (CALL worker_delete);
```

Case 2: For table worker_joining_date and worker_leaving_date instead of the row to be deleted I want to add a column worker_deleted and set that as true.

If there is some other way to get the above two cases is also welcomed.

Comment: The language specification goes before the `AS` and you only need **one** DECLARE block (before the first BEGIN) for all variables, not one block each time you need a new variable.

Comment: If you want to return some result you need to use a function, not a procedure

Comment: That sounds like you nete a foreign key with `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

Comment: How can we use the single function to delete the rows in multiple tables? I just need a way to return the 'id' everytime to delete and not write the table names in function.